# Calculator results weird

Tags: javascript, calculator

my calculator is out putting something weird with the results I have added it to jsfiddle for you guys to take a quick look at.

If I put 4000 as my principal and 1 year and I put 1% interest it repeats the same values for the principal and the interest, it also skips every other month, but if i put a interest rate of 20% it starts counting down the results of the principal and the interest correctly. Its kinda weird.

I think the problem is with the intr variable but im not quite sure how to fix it.

```
   function totalF(){
    var body = document.body;
    var tbl = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.setAttribute('id', 'results');
    var tblBody = document.createElement('tbody');
    var tndiv = document.getElementById('tdcontainer');

    for (var j = 1; j < payments; j++){
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

        temp = round(principal);
        intr = round((monthly * payments) - principal);
    while(temp>0 && intr>0){    
        if(tndiv != null){
               var cell = document.createElement('td');
               var cell2 = document.createElement('td');
               var cell3 = document.createElement('td');            

               var ndiv =  round(temp);
               var intr = round((monthly * payments) - principal);
               var monthlyn = j;

                cell.innerHTML = ndiv;
                cell2.innerHTML = monthlyn;
                cell3.innerHTML = intr;

                row.appendChild(cell);
                row.appendChild(cell2);
                row.appendChild(cell3);

                j++;
            }

            temp-=monthly;
            intr-=monthly;
            tblBody.appendChild(row);

            }
        tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
        body.appendChild(tbl);
        tbl.setAttribute("border", "1");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code here also. It's about helping you now and someone else 2 years from now after your fiddle is gone.

Comment: @user874185, I get an error when using the jsfiddle, `Uncaught ReferenceError: calculate is not defined`.

Comment: That's a problem with the "onload wrapping" of jsfiddle. Not related to his code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Timestamp: 17.04.2012 23:13:22
Error: document.loandata.payment is undefined
Source File: http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/
Line: 86
```

Use `document.getElementById('loandata').payment` instead. Do the same for the other form elements or even better use `var form = document.getElementById('loandata');` and then `form.payment` etc.

You also try to access elements in an invalid way at other places. If an element has an ID, use `document.getElementById('yourId')` to access it, and not `document.yourId` or `document.someElement.yourId`.

Besides that, you need to add the missing quote after the semicolon:

```
<div id="visualization" style="width: 750px;></div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't of though that should make a difference.

Comment: im not quite sure that is correct, and line 86 is in the totalF() function and is towards the end of the function, can you be a little more specific on where to put this?

Comment: I dont think you quite understand what I am saying, if you look at this link this is the results for the calculator and it has the values of principal: 4000 years:1 interest: 1% and then interest 20% with the rest of it being the same. Please take a quick look. http://pastebin.com/JstDBaEH

Comment: also I think this may be my problem, at the end of the totalF() function I have intr-=monthly; if I take it out the principal starts counting down correctly on any interests value I input, however the interest always stays the same.

Comment: Ive also updated my code so you can test it out in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s7CKT/3/